What evolutionary pressures would lead to clowns?
In my world, there is a species scientifically named Homo ridiculus (funny human) (so, they are humans, just not Homo sapiens), commonly named clowns.
Some basic characteristics of them are:

They are negligibly senescent like naked mole-rats (the record for the longest life expectancy for clowns is 206 years old);
Compared to the average Homo sapiens, they have a better emotional and social intelligence, a better spatial and visual intelligence, a better musical intelligence, but a worse logical and mathematical intelligence (many of them are dyscalculics);
Compared to the average Homo sapiens, they have a better sense of eyesight, a somewhat better sense of smell, and a MUCH better sense of touch, but a somewhat worse sense of taste, and a MUCH worse sense of hearing;
The place on Earth that can be considered their cradle is Italy;
Both males and females do not tend to have facial hair, but both have colourful facial features (a bit like mandrills, but in a unisex way) (colourful facial features include reddish skin around the nose and the cheeks, and blueish skin around the eyes), and dominant adults males (the homologous to both orangutans with flanges  and silverback gorillas) are at least a little balding;
They tend to have raspy squeaky voices (at least, in comparison to the average Homo sapiens): the most common voice type for adult females is coloratura soprano (by opposition to lyric mezzo in adult female Homo sapiens), and the most common one for adult males is tenorino (by opposition to lyric baritone in adult male Homo sapiens);
The tallest clown stood 3.12 metres tall, and the shortest adult one stood only 0.48 metre tall, the heaviest one weighed 1000 kg, and the lightest adult one weighted only 4 kg, and their average adult height is 1.88 metre, and their average adult mass is 128 kg (so, they are on average somewhat taller, and heavier than the average Homo sapiens, but still lighter than gorillas);
They have MUCH larger feet and hands than Homo sapiens;
They produce a saliva venom with similar effects to both CBD and THC.

Given these characteristics, what species could they have evolved from and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?

"the heaviest one weighed 1000 kg" that's the weight of a full grown adult rhinoceros.

VTC:Needs More Focus. You get one and only one question. (a) Seriously,  the [tag:science-based] and [tag:mythical-creatures] tags used together? It's not prohibited, but still.... (b) A basic premise of evolution based on the vanishingly small amount we know about it is, "given enough time, pretty much anything is possible." (c) Asking for a list of evolutionary pressures is opinion-based and open-ended, both of which are prohibited. Worse, there isn't one pressure that leads to (e.g.) big feet, there are an untold number of pressures that lead to minute changes that would end up as big feet.

@JBH A list of traits is not multiple questions.  This question is quite well focused on just one thing: clowns.

@MontyWild Asking (a) what creature said clowns could have evolved from and (b) for a list of evolutionary pressures is, in fact, two questions.

@JBH two aspects of the one question: Clowns: how and where from.  You can't ask just for one of the two alone.

@MontyWild Are we really debating this? I can't be from Detroit without explaining how I got to Memphis? We've been holding people to the one-question rule (one question mark, no conjunctions) for years and evolution questions are almost always opinion-based anyway. Nothing about this post is well focused. Humanity can barely explain why we think humans are the way they are in hindsight. Trying to explain the factual evolution of a fantastic creature is a pure guess. Based on the [help] as it stands today, how would you objectively choose a best answer?

I withdrew my first comment because an answer was posted at the same time, precluding a complete overhaul. I make it 9 questions. Each characteristic is worthy of it's own explanation as to the pressure required to produce it (assuming any). That makes 9 answers. Are we expected to address all points in a single answer? That seems a tall order to me. A frame challenge explaining the limitations of our understanding and ability to produce any cause-and-effect reasoning justifying a particular explanation of their origins is the only answer - without writing an unfeasibly large dissertation.

Given what we know of Homo Ridiculus it's quite clear they descend from Italian politicians. The convoluted, self-centered Italian political caste always displayed the fundamental trait of ridiculousness. Centuries of selective inbreeding stimulated by preservation of ill-gotten privileges enhanced it to the point of creating a new species.

The question states it is asking about Homo Ridiculus if named in recent times, then genetic and physiological evidence should be all in agreement that H. Ridiculus evolved from some hominid. Which means the question "what species could they have evolved from" is already answered as best it can be answered: Some hominid.

If this species had evolved in recent times as pointed out by @GaultDrakkor then consider that humans had a lot of influence on the evolution.  People go out to some forest clearing to smoke some marijuana and notice some "clown monkeys", then go tell others about this.  People learn of this, go smoke more marijuana, look for the "clown people", and reward the best "clowns" with food, beer, and CBD gummies.  There may be more than one species of hominid in the forest but with convergent evolution they interbreed into a single species with the "right" features for "homo ridiculous".

Frame Challenge
I dont know the world that you are trying to build, but if you have evolutionary clowns, I am picking that it has somewhat of a whimsical or not-too-serious look.
In which case - Rather than trying to have a hard-science-esque, well reasoned explanation for each of their traits - instead go for the most absurd and to be quite frank clownish answer - afterall you have named them homo ridiculous - lean into that.
Why the evolutionary pressure for big hands - well that was to fit the oversized gloves that they made.
The only reason I answered is because as I read your list of traits, I found myself smiling at it for the originality and absurdity of it - so my answer is a Frame Challenge of sorts - Embrace the ridiculous part of Homo Ridiculous - and be silly with it

Hallelujah.....

I second this opinion. Clearly, the purpose of the clowns in your world is to be clowns. So, clown around! (pun intended)

By implication, clowns (Homo ridiculus) must have evolved on Earth, since there is an Italy.  The problem with clowns is that their traits seem maladaptive to primitive conditions, however, we need not presume that all their current traits evolved abruptly.
The first thing that must occur is that clowns must speciate.  Since they are most similar to humans, it is reasonable to presume that they speciated from humans.  In order to speciate while still living in the same area as humans, this would require an event of aneuploidy resulting in a change in the numbers of chromosomes such that crosses between humans and clowns were unlikely to be viable.  We can suppose that this event occured early in the development of human society, perhaps fifty thousand years ago.  It would also require the acquisition of some of the basic clown traits.
There are known genetic disorders that produce some of the traits desired, such as Williams syndrome, though this is likely not one of the changes that occur in clowns, so this is just an example to show that such changes are possible.  These changes could have also extended the clowns' lifespans and caused the changes in the nature of the clowns' intelligence.
Having shown that genetic changes are necessary to make clowns a species rather than a racial trait, we need top consider what environmental niche that clowns would fill.  As I have said previously, their traits seem maladaptive to a primitive society.  They would likely not survive readily in such an environment, but their very ridiculousness would provide an advantage in a post-farming society where the efforts of humans have created a surplus of food and a higher degree of safety.  By being entertaining, clowns would fill the role of pets, though given their intelligence, they would not be pets owned by an individual, but pets to an entire community or society.
Having become entertaining pets to a community or society of humans, there would be competition between clowns to become more entertaining.  Because they are cared for by humans who find them entertaining, ever more outrageously entertaining traits will evolve, though there will always be the pressure that going over the line from entertaining to obnoxious will be highly detrimental, since clowns who insult individual powerful humans or entire communities of humans too egregiously could be ostracised or killed.
Better social and emotional intelligence would be vital to clowns.  They would absolutely need to be able to judge how to be entertaining without being annoying.  Having deficits in logical and mathematical ability could be entertaining to humans.
By differing from humans and from other clowns, a clown would become more entertaining, while being similar to humans or even other clowns would be a disadvantage.  Being tall or short, fat or thin would be advantageous.  Boring, look-alike clowns would tend to be starved into an early grave, while the most outrageous-looking clowns would thrive.  The evolution of white skin and colourful facial features would have given the clowns with those traits a distinct advantage.  If these clowns' facial traits were developmentally unique like fingerprints, this would be an advantage to all clowns with this trait, as they would be individually distinct and therefore more memorable and entertaining to humans.
Likewise, facial hair is seen by humans as a sign of male sexual maturity, and large mature adult males can be seen as threatening to other humans, especially when they are unfamiliar.  Clowns are likely to be nomadic since their success depends upon novelty, so being potentially threatening is a disadvantage.  Being neotenous would allow them to retain unthreatening juvenile features.
In a similar vein, changes in the voices of clowns to make them higher pitched and squeaky would be another example of unthreatening neoteny, and the humorous differences would be advantageous.
The enlargement of the hands and feet would also be selected for due to their entertainment value to humans, and we can add expansion of the nose and ears too.  Naturally, these traits wouldn't be present in every clown due to the novelty of variability factor, but many clowns would have at least some of these traits.
Given the necessity to be entertaining, increased sensitivity and dexterity would be advantageous, though this would be combined with learned skills and social intelligence to pretend to be clumsy.  Just because clumsiness is entertaining to humans doesn't mean that it's completely advantageous due to the potential for injury.  The ability to appear clumsy while having the ability to avoid actual injury is even more advantageous.
Being able to produce a 'venom' in their saliva similar to the effects of cannabis is difficult to justify in an adult clown, since a clown that bites would seem to be threatening to humans.  However, it would take time for a clown to mature and learn how best to be uniquely entertaining and develop their unique 'schtick'.  Very young clowns who have not yet developed their schtick could be at risk of abuse from humans, and the ability to bite and inject a venom that quickly gives the victim a 'high' that makes them relaxed and more susceptible to being entertained, while alleviating the pain of the bite (and reducing the chances of infection would also be good) would reduce the harm that an 'ugly' crowd of hostile humans could do to clowns.  I would consider this to be an unlikely mutation, even if there was no modification to the clowns' teeth and the venom was present only in saliva.
Being a highly variable species, it is inevitable that not every clown will have every clownish trait.  Not every clown will naturally have a colourful face or a large nose or big ears, hands or feet.  Their emotional and artistic intelligence will allow these clowns to artificially enhance their deficient traits, for example by using greasepaint to add or enhance their colourful clownish facial features.  Clowns may interbreed with humans occasionally, but these matings would necessarily be infertile, otherwise they wouldn't be a species, but only a racial group.

For the record, I'm not the down voter.
